# Application crashes if (own) dll try to allocate a few MB of RAM

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I'm not a good c++ programmer and I'm not very familiar creating DLLs for other application. My main programming language is Java so I'm having a little trouble with coding c++ and compiling with MinGW. However, as we need some small portion of "native" code for our main application (which is coded in Cobol) I was needed to try to do this with c++.
In general my DLL has a small footprint of memory usage as I'm doing nothing special with it. This DLL is mainly there to communicate with an external process using sockets.

As far as I can tell the DLL itself is fine and my problem must be more "specific" and is not a general c++ coding problem. Somewhere in my code I try to allocate some "large" amount of RAM with `char buf[size];` and later read file content into this buffer.

*size* can be a few kilobyte up to a few megabyte (not more than 10MB). **If the size is getting somewhere near to 1MB our main application crashes after above mentioned statement** (I pinpoint this down to that statement using logging outputs). If I compile my DLL as an EXE file and test the function directly (using Windows console) all is going fine and no crash happens. Even if I use several more MB for this buffer there is no problem with it. This leads me to suspect that there must be some sort of upper limit on memory usage using my DLL which causes the main application to crash hardly if my dll try to grab more memory as it may be allowed to.

**So my question is**:
Could it be that there is some sort of upper limit a DLL can/may use? And if yes, is there some kind of compiling switch or option I need to use while generating my DLL to overcome this limitation?
Our main application is using several other DLLs which using way more memory as my DLL try to use so this is not a limitation of our main application.

Here is the whole function which try to read the file:

```
/**
 * Read file content as Base64 Data
 */
char* readFileAsBase64(const char* filename) {
    FILE *file;
    if(!fileExists(filename)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    long size = (long)fileSize(filename);
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    char ch;
    // Crach happens here if 'size' is too large
    char buf[size];
    /* copy the file */
    for(long i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if(ferror(file)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if(!feof(file)) {
            buf[i] = ch;
        }
    }

    if(fclose(file)==EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return b64_encode(buf, size);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that 'allocates' this RAM? It sounds like you are blowing the stack, but until I see actual code I can't be sure.

Comment: `char buf[size]; ` inside a function would normally be implemented as a stack allocation. Stack is a limited resource and is not suitable for really large things (Where large is relative to platform). It also is automatically released at function exit, so isn't something that can be returned to your caller. The alternative is dynamic allocation, which may have some other issues.

Comment: `char buf[size];` is VLA and non-standard if `size` is not compile-time constant. In both cases, it is allocated on stack so it is fairly limited and should never be used. Just use `std::vector` which is the safe equivalent of `new char[size]` for java arrays.

Comment: If `size` is not a compile-time constant in your `char buf[size];` then it is called a _variable-length array (VLA)_, which is not a standard C++ feature. To dynamically allocate a buffer, you could either use manual memory management with `new` and `delete` (not recommended) or just use a standard container. For example, `std::vector<char> buf(size);` to allocate, and then `data(buf)` to access.

Comment: Okay thanks - I understand the problem. I need to modify my function and use some other way to save the file content... I'm a newbee I see

Comment: I agree with @AviBerger here this seems to be the case here. try allocating the buffer by using the new keyword in c++ `char* buff = new char[size];`  and don't forget to remove it after use using the delete[] directive on the variable as soon as you're done with it (likely before the end of your function, before all returns) 1MB is exactly the size of the stack on windows so given that you are using windows I assume this is a stack problem

Comment: It would/couild look more [like this](https://pastebin.com/y0Y6MJKe), but honestly it would be better if your b64 encoder (and thus your function here) returned a `std::string` instead.

Comment: Be aware that dynamically allocated memory has to be released when you are done with it. If you are returning a dynamically allocated char buffer to your COBOL program, you will also need a matching call into your dll when you are done with it to release the buffer.

Comment: @AviBerger Thanks for this hint. Luckily this buffer is just used inside my DLL and could be deleted after the internal use.

Comment: Good. Both the suggested std::string and std::vector clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a stack allocation (and not legal C++ either).

Simple fix is to use a `std::string`

```
#include <string>

...
std::string buf
buf.resize(size);
...
return b64_encode(buf.data(), size);
```

No other code changes needed. Although you could make further changes to use `std::string` throughout your code, instead of using raw pointers.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Yes my code is "ugly" I know. I c&p some portions from several "how tos" for my use. The b64_encode function is one of this. I had some kind of headache to get this all to work. Unbeliveable how different c++ from java is ... This could take a few minutes for me to do it java. But tooked several hours if not a whole day to get this to work in c++...

Comment: C++ and Java are radically different. The similar syntax hides a lot.

Comment: @MartinFernau Although you haven't shown it so I can't be sure, my concern is that you are leaking memory in `b64_encode`. Avi Berger had similar concerns.

Comment: The function behind ```b64_encode``` uses a new "char *enc" buffer which is allocated using ```malloc``` (and ```realloc``` to resize during its procession). The function returns that buffer after its work. For my understanding I need to ```free``` this pointer after the use of the return of my readFileAsBase64 function.

Comment: @MartinFernau That's right, and as Avi said you will need to add a new function in your DLL to do this.